# dividing n with 2 until you get odd number (Function)

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic, graphing-functions

So I'm not really sure how to phrase this question so i apologize in advance.

I am trying to find a function that matches the image below. I generated this image by iterating through hole numbers between 1 and 100. Then I counted how many divisions of 2 it could do until it would reach an odd number (The y axis number of divisions).

So my question is, is there any function that matches this graph at the **points** not necessarily the lines? (I am thinking some kind of trick with modular)

[image: This is the Graph!!!]

Comment: [OEIS A007814](http://oeis.org/A007814)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\log_2x}1-\Big\lceil x/2^n-\lfloor x/2^n\rfloor\Big\rceil$

Comment: How do you graph that on for example Desmos

Comment: @JökullSnærGylfason: Sorry, but what do you mean by "graph that", and what is "Desmos"???

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator Graphing calculator that graphs functions

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with this utility.

Comment: How do you calculate outputs for any x

Comment: @JökullSnærGylfason: Well, you can replace "$\infty$" with "$\log_2x$, that will allow you to calculate $f(x)$ within a finite number of operations. In fact, I will update my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understand you question correctly, this is just the number of 2's in factorisation of given number... E.g. $52=2^2*13$, so you can divide by 2 two times, $24=2^3*3$, so you can divide three times etc.

Anyway, if you want you may define $until$ recursively:

$until ( property(x),\ step(x),\ x_{starting}) = \\
-\ if\ property(x_{starting})\ then\ x\\
-\ otherwise\ until ( property(x),\ step(x),\ step(x_{starting}))$

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did that to make that graph :D

Comment: It is the solution to $f(2n-1)=0, f(2n)=f(n)+1$ for positive integer $n$

Answer (score 1):

This function is called the 2-adic valuation.  It can be defined on $\mathbb Z^*$ (as you do) or on $\mathbb Q^*$, on a number field or on $\mathbb Z_2$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order